# How can I delete the line below my Tab layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tabhost

I'm sory for my poor Englisch. I come from Holland, and I'm just 14.

I am practicing my android development skills, but I have a problem. If I create a tab menu comes a horizontal line below. With a black background you don't see it, but if it is white you'l see it.
![http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/503/emulator.png][1]

My question is rather simple. How can I delete that line? The XML layoutfile of this tab menu is displayed below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try by removing `android:padding="5dp"` from the `FrameLayout`.

Comment: If I do that the line is disappeared, but the padding ofcourse also. How can I bring the padding back without the line?

Comment: You can try margin or use padding in the views that goes inside the framelayout.

If any answer solves your problem don't forget to click the right mark of the corresponding answer.

Comment: I have did it by your way, and I used the padding in the XML file. That works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried xml attributes in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html)?

Comment: I found android:tabStripEnabled there. I think that's the solution, but where and how must I used it? I am new in the android development, so I haven't any experience with that.

Comment: tabStrip is a line the same color as active tab, that goes to the left and right of it, just below inactive tabs